# Facebook PHP API code not working with "Pages" to get Wall posts

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

```
<?php
require '../src/facebook.php';
try
{
// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '120875194666085',
  'secret' => '0272027b5c5c1dabde81096497970c56',
  'scope' => 'read_stream',
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();


if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me/feed');

  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);

    $user = null;
  }
}

// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'read_stream'));
}

}
catch(FacebookApiException $e){}
?>
<?php

     if ($user): ?>
    <?php else: ?>
      <div>
        Login using OAuth 2.0 handled by the PHP SDK:
        <a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">Login with Facebook</a>
      </div>
    <?php endif ?>

    <?php if ($user): ?>

    <?php 
        for($i = 0; $i < 25; $i++)
           {
        echo "<br />"; 
        echo $user_profile['data'][$i]['from']['name'];
              echo " : "; 
        echo $user_profile['data'][$i]['message']; 
           }
    ?>
    <?php endif ?>
```

This worked just fine for normal accounts, but when I tried to log in with a Facebook "Pages" account, it didn't work at all. Any help on this matter? Also, when I got to the Facebook Graphs API documentation, even those links don't give me a proper feed of the Pages wall. From what I had gathered, I had to 
https://graph.facebook.com/[company page id]/feed??access_token=[access_token] 
to get it to work (which I am not sure how to translate into the Facebook API.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access Fan Page Feeds as long as you have any [access_token](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page).

If you have a valid authorised user that is logged in

```
$fan_page_feed = $facebook->api('/COMPANY_PAGE_ID/feed');
```

will return a JSON object containing feed data.

Alternatively you could use the applications access_token to get the information. This example gets the feed from the [Facebook Platfrom](http://www.facebook.com/platform) page (For the sake of conciseness, the script also assumes everything will work perfectly - you should implement your own error handling as you see fit):

```
<html><head></head>
<body>
<pre>
<?php
require ('facebook.php');

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
            'appId'  => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
            'secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
            'cookie' => true
        ));

$result = $facebook->api('oauth/access_token', array('client_id'=>'YOUR_APP_ID', 'client_secret'=>'YOUR_APP_SECRET', 'grant_type'=>'client_credentials'));
// $result should contain 'access_token=VALID_ACCESS_TOKEN'
$access_token = explode('=',$result);
$fan_page_feed = $facebook->api('/19292868552/feed', array('access_token'=>$access_token[1]));

print_r($fan_page_feed);
?>
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```